# document.getelementbyId() returns null even though script is at the end of file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to execute a JS function which is written at the bottom of .aspx file.

Div tag:

```
 <div id="div_NRContainer" oninit="div_NRContainer_Init" class="panelContainer" runat="server">
```

after this under script tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     function show_tabs(id) {

                var nrcontainer = document.getElementById("div_NRContainer");
                alert(nrcontainer);
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle or snippet with your code?

Comment: @hitesh. do you want me to add complete code here?

Comment: You're using ASP.net and an ID. Can you be sure that the `runat="server"` attribute doesn't change the ID dynamically? Please can you post the output HTML?

Comment: create a demo if possible with https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @HiteshMisro - or the OP could use the inbuilt stack snippets?

Comment: @evolutionxbox. I added runat="server". still it returns null

Comment: @DKR - that's not what I asked... can you post the rendered HTML which ASP.net outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a server side control. Chances are, that Asp.Net has changed the Id of your element. If your script is on the same aspx page this could should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function show_tabs(id) {
         var nrcontainer = document.getElementById("<%= div_NRContainer.ClientID %>");
         alert(nrcontainer);
     }
</script>
```

Read up on ClientIDMode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is what is was trying to get OP to understand... ugh

Comment: But I have a question. when it was not set as "runat=server", was it a serverside control??

Comment: If an element on an aspx page does not contain `runat="server"` it is not a server-side control.

Answer (score -1):

The question is incomplete,In the mentioned question,calling of show_tabs method is missing. It matters where you are calling, If you call once the page loads you will get it easily. call the method in $(document.ready).